# Is it possible to do mediational analysis on trial-level data, including random subject and items factors?

Tags: mixed-model, random-variable, random-effects-model, mediation

I have words that are rated on several different dimensions. Each of say 30 subjects rates a set of say 30 words. I am curious if some feature of the words is related to some rated dimension of the words, and if this is mediated by some other rated dimension of the words.

I am wondering if it's possible to analyze this at the trial level, while also including random subject and item intercepts?

Comment: Are "item" and "word" the same thing ? It sounds like crossed random effects would be OK, but it's not clear what you mean by "some rated dimension" and "some other related dimension". Can you provide more information about your data ?